# In Django, how can I generate csrf token when not using templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm writing pages in my own code, not using Django templates.  Because I'm overloaded on new things to learn and trying to get this done.

Now I had some easy cases with templates, and {% csrf_token %} worked just fine.  But they used render() and a template.

I have a bunch of custom HTML I can't immediately figure out how to put in a template, so I can't use render().  Instead, I return HttpResponse() applied to my page, and that does not deal with {% csrf_token %}.

How do I get that `<input>` element into the form part of my page?  I'm willing to generate the form from a template, but not the rest of the page.

Comment: If your Django template doesn't use `{%` or `{{` anywhere it won't be touched by the template engine. If you render your existing HTML as a Django template it won't be modified at all. There's no need to complicate things by recreating `csrf_token` outside of a template if you don't have a good reason to.

Comment: I'm not using a template, because I don't (yet) know how to get what I want with a template.  And I have a good reason for using csrf_token, since this uses the POST method and will change my database.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the CSRF token outside of a Django template by calling the appropriate function from the CSRF middleware:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def your_view(request):
    csrf_token = get_token(request)
    csrf_token_html = '<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{}" />'.format(csrf_token)
```

One thing to keep in mind is that Django templates don't really care about what you pass into them. They only touch content between `{% ... %}` and `{{ ... }}` tags. If your template is just static HTML, the Django template engine will not touch it at all and it'll be as if you served it as a normal file.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For anybody who also wants the matching `csrftoken` cookie, you can find it in `request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']`